# Socket c#. Создание сервера

Tags: c#, сервер, сокет, websocket

Есть Websocket сервер который написан с помошью неблокирующих Socket. Возможно ли не используя poll и select обрабатывать 10к+ соединений используя только Receive. Примерно так

```
start = Socket.Receive(buffer, start, count, SocketFlags.None, out error);
if (error != SocketError.Success && error != SocketError.WouldBlock)
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

какие ошибки не учитывает данный подход и каким является оптимальное время обработки одного сообщения(приём и отправка обратно) при нагрузке в 10к соединений одновременно?

Comment: Не вполне понятно, что у вас за метод такой - `Tcp.Receive`. Это сильно затрудняет понимание вопроса...

Comment: Tcp.Receive это стандартный вызов Socket.Receive .Net Framework. Подробнее можно посмотреть тут https://github.com/jackyt1988t/WebSocket. Смысл таков что можно ли ограничиться вызовом только этой функции для проверки ошибок сокета и что сулит это для производительности сервера